# Putting an working activity into a swipe tab view

Tags: java, android

Over the past week i've been struggling to add a working activity to a swipe tab view that uses fragments. I've literally no idea of where to start with this, the swipe tab view works on its own and the activity works on its own too can anyone help with this?

TabPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.learn2crack.tab;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;



public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragement for Android Tab
            return new MainActivity1();
        case 1:
           //Fragment for Ios Tab
            return new Maps();
       // case 2:
            //Fragment for Windows Tab
           // return new Maps();

        return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2; //No of Tabs
    }


    }
```

MainActivity1.java

```
package com.learn2crack.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



    interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
      /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
     }
     public class MainActivity1 extends FragmentActivity implements OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.rooms_view);



        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

        // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
        ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Software);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

        } else {
            // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
        final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
        int mCurrentPosition = -1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
            // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
            // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
            }

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sofware_view, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
            // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
            // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
            // below that sets the article text.
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args != null) {
                // Set article based on argument passed in
                updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
            } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
                // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
                updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
            }
        }

        public void updateArticleView(int position) {
            TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Software);
            article.setText(Rooms[position]);
            mCurrentPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
            outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
        OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;




        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
            int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

            // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Software));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
            // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Software) != null) {
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
            // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
            try {
                mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Notify the parent activity of selected item
            mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

            // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;




    static String Software[] = {
            "3D Studio Max 2014",
            "Adobe Creative Suite 6",
            "Agilent Agent",
            "Android SDK",
            "Audacity",
            "C Map Tools",
            "Cedar and Easy 68k",
            "Context",
            "CryEngine 3",
            "Derive V5.0",
            "Dreamweaver CS6",
            "Eclipse",
            "Face Modeller",
            "Flash CS6",
            "Image J",
            "Linux",
            "Matlab R2012A (Computing Toolbase)",
            "Matlab R2012A (Maths)",
            "Microsoft Project",
            "Microsoft SQL Sever Lite",
            "MinecraftEDU",
            "MiniTab 16",
            "MonoGame",
            "NetBeans 7.3.1",
            "Office 2013",
            "Oracle Client",
            "Photoshop CS6",
            "Premiere CS6",
            "Python 3.3.2",
            "QT 5.1",
            "R-Studio",
            "Rational Architect",
            "Steam",
            "SWI Pro Log",
            "Unreal UDK",
            "Visio 2012",
            "Visual Studio 2012",
            "Win A&D 7 Desktop",
            "Windows Mobile SDK",
            "Weka ML",
            "XNA Game Studio"};

   static  String Rooms []= { "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",




    };
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

sofware_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Software"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

rooms_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an activity into a `ViewPager`. However, you can convert `MainActivity1` to be a fragment.

Comment: Can you explain how i would do that please?

Comment: @user3092467: Well, you start by having it extend `Fragment` instead of `FragmentActivity`. To be honest, `MainActivity1` should not be a tab as presently written. `MainActivity1` does navigation within itself (first shows headlines, then replaces its own content with an article). That's fine, but that's not an appropriate flow for a tab. Show `HeadlinesFragment` in a tab, but then have a click launch another activity or otherwise replace the tabs. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sww4omntVjs&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF&index=2 for a discussion of navigation and tabs.